# Reading values from a file and storing them into a multidimensional array

Tags: c

I am new to C, so please let me know if you see something just obviously stupid on my part :)

### What I'm trying to do

I have a file that has newline separated string values that I I'm trying to read into my program so that I can use them to compare with other values.  I thought the best way to store them would in in a multidimensional array.  My code looks something like this:

```
char **data;
char *src_line;
int counter = 0; /* To keep track of how many items are in this array */
...
while(fgets(src_line,MAX_LINE_SIZE,fp_src_file) != NULL){
    int tmp = 0;
    while(src_line[tmp] != '\0'){
        if(src_line[tmp] == '\n'){
            src_line[tmp] = '\0';
        }
        tmp++;
    }
    strcpy(data[counter],src_line);
    counter++;
}
```

This segfaults during the strcpy.  Most of the resources I've found online that deal with multidimensional arrays do so with constant values.  I'm sure that this is probably not the best way to do this so..

### My questions

1. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?
2. What is the proper way to get an unknown number of items into a multi dimensional array.  Should I even be doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the part of the code where you're actually allocating memory for data? (Are you actually allocating memory?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, it's not clear to me if you're not allocating memory correctly for data, or if you're not allocating it at all :) data is a char**. You want it to be an array of character arrays, so you need to (a) allocate memory for the top-level array of char*s, and then (b) allocate memory for the arrays of chars themselves.

So if you have an unknown number of items the easiest solution is just to come up with a reasonable max and allocate enough for that max, or you can read through the file once just looking for \ns, count those, and then allocate memory for data appropriately, etc. Or you could start out with an assumption about how many lines you're going to have, allocate data accordingly, and then if/when you run out of space create a new array of double the size and copy everything over. That sounds like more work than you want.

Another approach that might be simpler -- fstat the whole file, and just create one buffer big enough to hold the whole thing. Read the whole file in. Iterate through, switch the \ns for \0s and count lines as you go. Then create a char** of size == the number of lines you saw and assign them to the start of each line. Voila -- you have a string per line and you didn't have to do as much mucking around with memory allocation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions and help!  Yes, I accidentally left out the part where I allocated the memory, but you still solved the problem.  The issue is that I was trying to allocate memory for data[counter] but never allocated memory for data[] itself!

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint on your existing code; strcpy does not actually allocate storage for you, you need to give it a buffer to copy the data to.

```
data[counter] = malloc(strlen(src_line)+1);
strcpy(data[counter],src_line);
```

About reading the file in a more elegant way; since you're reading the whole file anyway;

- fstat the file to get the size and malloc file size + 1. Set fileBuffer[size] to 0.
- read the whole file with one "read" call into your malloc'd block.
- Replace all \n with \0 in your block while counting the number of newlines.
- Allocate a line pointer array of the correct size (ie number of newlines + 1 if the file does not end with a newline)
- Loop through the file, setting consecutive pointers in the array to the first memory address after a \0 (first line is a special case and points straight to your malloc'd block)

That way you have all of the file allocated in one block (and free'd in one block) while having pointers to each line.

Comment: My guess is this will segfault too since data itself is not allocated :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I wish I could mark both of your answers as the correct as they both have very useful data.  I appreciate your explanation of how to read in the entire file.  I believe that will be the best route for this particular application, but until you mentioned it I had no idea about `read()`!