# Read a huge matrix file in C

Tags: c, file, optimization, file-io, matrix

I have a huge `100,000x100,000`matrix (txt file) that I use to calculate the fitness of a chromosome in Genetic Algorithm. My population size is 100 and the generation size is 1000. So I am reading this file 100,000 times.

GA is written in `C` and I am not familiar with `C`. What is the efficient way to read this matrix file in `C`. Is there any other way that I can optimize this.

Thank you.

`Edit:`

I am sorry, Its a 100,000 X 100,000 matrix file. I can't keep this in memory as it needs around 37GB. I want to read each time I needs it.

Comment: There was actually a recent question on a somewhat similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945059/reading-values-from-a-file-and-storing-them-into-a-multidimensional-array/8945146#8945146 You'll also be interested in [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) and [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/).

Comment: I hope you have a lot of RAM, assuming you are using 32 bit integers, 100 copies of your matrix would take 40GB of memory.

Comment: Why are you reading it 100,000 times? Is the file modified in between reads?

Comment: It didn't sound to me like he was planning on holding a bunch of copies of the matrix -- the matrix itself doesn't change, right? -- but he's clearly planning on reading it multiple different times. Also not clear -- why can't you just keep it in memory?

Comment: @PaulEastlund: I assumed that each individual would have a copy that he is comparing to the one read in.  But I could be misconstruing the quesiton.

Comment: I am sorry, Its a 100,000 X 100,000 matrix file. I can't keep this in memory as it needs around 37GB. I want to read each time I needs it.

Comment: So you want to repeatedly read in something you can't fit in memory all at one time? So you're going to be processing it as you read it in some way? I think you need to talk about that piece of it -- what sort of processing you need to do,  which pieces of memory you need to have in memory at once, etc. For instance, if all you needed to do was sum up all of the values in the matrix, this would be very easy. Presumably that is not the case.

Comment: Without knowing what you want to do with it, we can't help you. Explain GA, does it need to read data in naturally (sequel) or does it hop from one end to another?
If it is possible, create hash-tree like structure and use appropriate hashing function.
If you need to read it sequentially, use some kind of ring buffer.

You could also use some database library in case you are not into getting dirty with filedescriptors and C pointers.

Comment: I'm not saying that algorithm improvements wouldn't make sense for you, but you do know you can buy computers with much more than 40 GB of memory for a couple of thousand dollars/euros/pounds, right?

Comment: @han: Well, throwing that much money onto a problem that *can* be solved by simply using the right software approach seems rather... wasteful and unnecessary.

Comment: @DarkDust: I agree with you on that point, but if this is a real business problem (or a side issue in a well-funded research project) then the hardware option should not be ruled out.

Answer (score 4):

Read about [`mmap()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap), which is useful for large files.

Answer (score 2):

What do you know about the data in the matrix?  Is the data mostly zeros, so the matrix is [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)?  If that is the case then only the non-zero elements need to be stored. [Here](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/) is an example C library for operations on Sparse Matrices.

Is there any [symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) in the matrix?  If it has diagonal symmetry for example, only half of the data needs to be stored.

EDITED to add:

There obviously isn't 37GB of mathematical *[information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information)* in your input data, so much of of the data in the matrix can be discarded without affecting the result of your program. I would guess that matrix elements smaller than a certain value can be flushed to zero, which would have the effect of converting your matrix to a sparse matrix, if it isn't already sparse.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to re-read the file each time ? you could just read it once and keep it in memory, this way you don't have to worry about optimizing the reading of the file, since it's done once. Assuming this is a matrix of floats and that a float is 4 bytes, 10000*10000*4/1024/1024 = 381MBs

Edit: 
If it's 100000x100000, then I think you could scale the floating point values to bytes (0-255) this way you need just 9GBs instead of 40GBs.

Comment: I am sorry, Its a 100,000 X 100,000 matrix file. I can't keep this in memory as it needs around 37GB. I want to read each time I needs it

Comment: It's 100,000 x 100,000 not 10,000 x 10,000.

Comment: I see, then no I don't think there's a way to avoid swapping, even when using mmap, However, you could scale the floating point values to bytes (0-255) this way you need just 9GBs instead of 40GBs

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Reynold already wrote, `mmap` is the way to go to access the file. It's simple, fast, and places the whole memory management burden onto the kernel instead of your code.

Additionally you might need to think about how to represent the data in memory. For example, if you're analyzing genes AFAIK there are only four types. So you can encode one gene with 2 bits, or 4 genes in one byte. This way you'd have more work to do to fetch/store genes but you'd need "only" 2.5GB to store 100.000 x 100.000 entries.

If your data contains lots of zeros, you might want read up on [sparse matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) which can –depending on the input–  dramatically compress your data.